# Has anyone experience with I.E. lacking website performence when used with a VPS?

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, citrix

Recently we succesfully completed a portal project which is now online.
It was well tested and worked seemingly fine until one of our customers used I.E. with a Citrix VPS and the portal took 12 seconds to fully ready the page.

While Chrome without VPS takes 1-2 seconds varying on caching and I.E. without caching takes around 5 seconds.

After a session with the customer we could see that the HTML and SQL was loading in 3 seconds but the JavaScript took 8 seconds.

We are currently only using Bootstrap and DataTables as plugin with some custom code aside of it.

I was wondering if someone has experience with this or does have any recommendations on how to improve this?

If someone needs additional information let me know.

Regards, Jacco

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/dn255009%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) use F12 developer performance tools to analyze UI performance, and use [F12 developer Network tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255004(v=vs.85)) to check the request spend time.

To the Bootsrtap and DataTables reference, please try to use CDN reference.

To your JavaScript code, you could delay JavaScript loading, using the asynchronous loading and Async request, reduce DOM Access, then, using Gzip to compression JavaScript file.

More detail information, you could check the following articles:

[JavaScript Performance](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_performance.asp)

[8 tips for improving your JavaScript performance](https://www.monitis.com/blog/8-tips-for-improving-your-javascript-performance/)

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv,

Thank you for your reply, I calculated the times with the Network tools.
The bootstrap and datatables library has been saved local to save time from calling another host.
But I'm sure we didn't use an asynchronous call for the scripts, this is something we will look into and see if this already saves some time.
Regards, Jacco